# Pausing application Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, task

I'm new here and I trying to creating an app for Windows Phone, just for testing.
I'm trying to create a Splash Screen page, where I have 2 images. Show Image 1, stop for some seconds and then show Image 2.

But I can't use System.Threading.Thread.Sleep() on Windows Phone 8.1, so searching around the net, I found the Task.Delay.

I tried to use "Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));" but it's useless. The software just pass through...

Here's the code:

```C#
BitmapImage Imgchange = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ms-appx:/Imagens/Intros/Intro01.png", UriKind.Absolute));
Background.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
Background.Source = Imgchange;
Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
// USED Task.Delay here, but this don't work
Imgchange = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ms-appx:/Imagens/Menus/Untitled-1.png", UriKind.Absolute));
Background.Source = Imgchange;
```

I also tried to find some codes about the Task.Wait(), but I had no luck at all.

Anyway, sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You can probably storyboard this animation with KeyFrames pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the `Task.Delay` by using the keyword `await`

```
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

Comment: Didn't work, I tried to use await, but still passing through the first image and go to the second one.